# Android include javax.sound.sampled.*

Tags: android, audio, import, waveform

For an Android app (for Android version 2.1),I want to analysis a sound file and get the frequency. Therefore I want to include javax.sound.sampled.* for that purpose. How can I get that? Any external jar file can do it for me? Any such jar file is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not support it :(

Answer (score 0):

A Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) library should be usable for your purpose. Unfortunately I cannot recommend any as I haven't tried them myself.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of google searching, finally stumbled across this FFT library, written in pure java, works works great on Android: http://moonblink.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/HermitLibrary/doc/ca/uol/aig/fftpack/package-summary.html

Note that you will need some other bits from the hermitlibrary as well, but it's pretty straightforward. It's fast enough that I can FFT a stereo stream, manipulate the spectrum, and re-synthesise the audio in realtime :-D