# Is JLayer supported by Android

Tags: java, android

I've seen a lot of question about playing .mp3 files using [JLayer](http://javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) in Android, a lot of these questions have accepted answers meaning that they succeeded in using JLayer to process .mp3 files.

I downloaded the `.jar` and imported it into my project. I then implemented the following to test if it is working:

```
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = getApplication().getAssets().openFd("testing.mp3");
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
//JLayer below
Player player = new Player(stream);
player.play();
```

When I run my application I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat;
```

I did some research and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026164/android-include-javax-sound-sampled) that javax is not supported by android. I had a look through JLayer.jar and found that in `JavaSoundAudioDevice.java` is the following imports:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info;
```

so, if javax is not supported by android and JLayer uses javax, how does other people get it working? - as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676617/the-import-javazoom-cannot-be-resolved#5676798) question..

Comment: go [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414321/android-mp3-jlayer-missing-data) way - the first code snippet is more or less how you should decode your data

Comment: btw why do you have to use JLayer?

Comment: @pskink I found NetBeans project online that uses JLayer. I'm trying to build the project for android. I can remove JLayer and replace it with MediaPlayer if I like, but I decided to try and use JLayer. Is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: sure you can use it but the performance can suffer...